# iOS PFObject iterate to get all key/value pairs

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have an array of PFObjects called "customers" that has 15 value/keys pairs in it.  I want to use these key/pair values at run time.  How can I iterate through each pair and assign the value to NSString?

Below I have a snippet that works but I have to enter the key at design time, which means if I ever change anything I have to update code.  I don't want that.  I need to loop each key/value pair at run time.

```
for (PFObject customer in customers) {
    NSString *str = [customer valueForKey:@"key"];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for downvote without comment.  big help.

Comment: An array having value/keys pairs in it is a dictionary.

Comment: In Xcode it says customer is an NSArray.  Is it wrong?

Comment: That is to say, customers comes from PFobjects (parse.com) and according to their documentation I have objects with key/pairs and Xcode says that object is NSArray, hence my title.

Comment: Have you examined the value of `customers` in the debugger, or printed it out with `NSLog`? That will quickly tell you if you have an array or dictionary.

Comment: Your opening sentence makes no sense. An array does not contain value/key pairs. An array contains objects. What are the actual type of objects in your `customers` array?

Comment: Consider restating the question to:  "I have an array of PFObjects retrieved from parse.  These objects each have a property called _____ (fill in that blank).  I'd like to iterate this array and end up with an array of the values of that property"

Comment: try `NSLog(@"%@", customers);` - this will tell you what class customers actually is. Then you should find documentation for this class and study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an array of dictionaries, which means that you need to additionally loop over the keys in the dictionary, then access their values.
Like so:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"Key1" : @"Value1"}, @{@"Key2" : @"Value2"}, @{@"Key3" : @"Value3"}];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dict.allKeys);
    for (NSString *key in dict.keyEnumerator) {
        NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value %@", key, dict[key]);
    }
}
```

Here, array is a collection of dictionaries, which means that when you loop over it, or access it like `array[0]`, then you will retrieve a dictionary. You must further access the keys of the dictionary, then access their values respectively, by doing something like:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
NSString *key = // get the key from somewhere, maybe a loop
NSString *value = dict[key];
```

Finally, it is possible to loop over just the values of the dictionary, by doing:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
for (NSArray *values in dict.allValues) {
    NSLog(@"Values: %@", values);
}
```

In full:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"Key1" : @"Value1"}, @{@"Key2" : @"Value2"}, @{@"Key3" : @"Value3"}];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dict.allKeys);
    for (NSString *key in dict.keyEnumerator) {
        NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value %@", key, dict[key]);
    }
}

for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    for (NSArray *values in dict.allValues) {
        NSLog(@"Values: %@", values);
    }
}
```

Comment: The property allValues is what I was looking for as far as the loop is concerned.  However, (and perhaps this is another question) but the array is created using Parse.com from their method findObjectsInBackgroundwithBlock.  When I use your code above I get the following error:  -[PFObject allValues]: unrecognized selecter sent to isntance

Comment: You could try using `allKeys` and see what that gets you. I don't use parse.com, but that doesn't mean I can't help. I presumed you were using an NSDictionary, however that isn't the case. The docs say that `allKeys` will `an array of keys contained in this object`, so that wouldn't be a bad place to start.

Comment: I also want to point out that your declaration for `customer` in your for-loop is wrong. You should be using `PFObject`, which is the correct type. It should also be a pointer, with a * out the front, like the string.

Comment: allKeys works.  I can use that to loop through using valueForKey, since I know the key now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `PFObjects` representing customers, and you'd like to have an array of strings representing their names.  You'll need to know the name of the attribute on the customer object that contains the name, lets call it "name", as a guess.  (The OP has it as @"key", but I'm assuming that's the result of confusion).

```
// replace @"name" with the name of the string attribute representing
// the customer's name (find it in your data browser) 
NSMutableArray *customerNames = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (PFObject *customer in customers) {
    [customerNames addObject:[customer valueForKey:@"name"]];
}
NSLog(@"The names are %@", customerNames);
```